# Getting Expired Purchases And Associated Features

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am updating our in-house purchase system. While doing this, I had to move the service expiration date from the client table to the purchase table so each system could expire separately. I am trying to update the SQL statement to get systems that need to be billed, but am running into issues. Below is a simplified example of what I need:

Purchase Table

```
ID   Product   ClientID   SystemID   IsSystem ExpireDate
1    System1     12          1       1        9/22/2015
2    Feature1    12          1       0        NULL
3    Feature2    12          1       0        9/22/2016
4    System2     12          2       1        9/22/2016
5    Feature1    12          2       0        9/22/2015
6    Feature2    12          2       0        NULL
```

In the example above, I would need to get lines 1, 2 and 3. What I need to do is:

1. Look at each system to see if the ExpireDate is less than or equal to a given date (say today)
2. If it is, take all rows with a matching ClientID and SystemID reguardless of ExpireDate

Although line 5 would be expired, it would not get included because the system it is a part of has not expired.

This is getting inserted into a much larger SQL statement spanning several tables, but I should be able to extrapolate from an example with this table.

Comment: Are you getting an error?   Please post your query so we can help debug it.

Comment: Your example for line 5 contradict to your first rule.and second rule.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Line 5 is a feature. I need to only check the expiration date for IsSystem = 1, and then include all purchases with a matching SystemID.

Comment: I see, maybe you should include that info in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably best accomplished using a common table expression that gets the expired client and systemIDs and then checks every row in your table against that list:

```
WITH expired AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ClientID,
        SystemID
    FROM purchase

    WHERE
        CONVERT(DATE, ExpireDate) <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
        AND isSystem = 1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM purchase p

WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM expired WHERE p.ClientId = ClientID AND p.SystemId = SystemId)
```